# spray-json: Serialize a generic trait

Tags: scala, implicit, traits, spray-json

spray-json relies on the presence of an in-scope, implicit `JsonWriter[T]` when calling `toJson` on an instance of `T`.

Say I have a trait with several concrete subtypes, each of which has a JsonWriter:

```
trait Base
case class Foo(a: Int) extends Base
case class Bar(a: Int, b: Int) extends Base
implicit val FooFormat = jsonFormat1(Foo)
implicit val BarFormat = jsonFormat2(Bar)

def go(o: Base) = {
    o.toJson
}
```

`go` doesn't compile because there's no JsonWriter for Base, even though there *are* writers for all of the concrete subtypes.

How can I reorganize this code such that generic functions of `Base` use the appropriate json formatters?

Comment: Wrap your implicits in an object and import to the scope of `go`. You may still have an issue with the trait itself but those implicits aren't going to be available for `go` unless you import it.

Comment: Sorry if my snippet was unclear -- my question is about how to write a function on Base that uses the appropriate concrete implicit, assuming the set of these implicits is properly in-scope where it needs to be. As it stands I know how to write `go` if its argument is `(o: Foo)`, but not `(o: Base)`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a generic method with type and context bounds. Like this:

```
def go[T <: Base : JsonWriter](t: T) = t.toJson
```

Comment: That's nice. is the `: JsonWriter` essentially equivalent to `(implicit fmt: JsonWriter[T])`?

Comment: Exactly! `def f[T : X](t: T): T = t` will be  `f: [T](t: T)(implicit evidence$1: X[T])T`

Answer (score 3):

Marshalling `Base` would require a `JsonFormat`. Following is one of the ways to approach the stated issue.

```scala
import spray.json._

object BaseJsonProtocol extends DefaultJsonProtocol {
  implicit val FooFormat = jsonFormat1(Foo)
  implicit val BarFormat = jsonFormat2(Bar)

  implicit object BaseJsonFormat extends RootJsonFormat[Base] {
    def write(obj: Base) = obj match {
      case x: Foo ⇒ x.toJson
      case y: Bar ⇒ y.toJson
      case unknown @ _ => serializationError(s"Marshalling issue with ${unknown}")
    }

    def read(value: JsValue) = {
      value.asJsObject.getFields("a","b") match {
        case Seq(JsNumber(a)) => Foo(a.toInt)
        case Seq(JsNumber(a), JsNumber(b)) => Bar(a.toInt, b.toInt)
        case unknown @ _ => deserializationError(s"Unmarshalling issue with ${unknown} ")
    }
  }
 }
}
```

As a result, the `BaseJsonProtocol` can be used to marshall an instance of `Base` as follows.

```scala
import BaseJsonProtocol._

def go(o: Base) =  o.toJson

assert (go(Foo(10)).convertTo[Foo] == Foo(10))
assert (go(Foo(10).asInstanceOf[Base]).convertTo[Foo] == Foo(10))
assert (go(Bar(10,100)).convertTo[Bar] == Bar(10, 100))
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

I realized one solution is to make `go` a generic function with a type bound, and declare the implicit value..."explicitly"

```
def go[T <: Base](t: T)(implicit fmt: JsonWriter[T]) =
    t.toJson
```

Now the function can compile because the `JsonWriter` is promised as a function parameter, and each call site can pull in a concrete implementation of `JsonWriter[T]` depending on the context (`FooFormat` or `BarFormat`).

Comment: Without a `JsonFormat` for `Base`, for instance: `go(anyBase)` where `val anyBase: Base = Foo(1)` won't compile.

Comment: yeah that's a good point -- beyond your implementation of BaseJsonFormat, is there another way to implement it that doesn't require a   case statement that enumerates all subtypes of Bar? Conceptually it seems like all the relevant logic (the concrete JsonWriters + type hierarchy) is already defined, and it was bothering me that somewhere I had to duplicate these pieces of code again -- either in a BaseJsonFormat or in separate go functions for each type.